# Is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\sqrt{k}}{k}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm wondering whether the following series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\sqrt{k}}{k}$$

is convergent or not. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: conditionally convergent b/c alternating series and $$\lim_{k \to \infty} = 0$$

Comment: Why is it alternating? @ChristopherMarley

Comment: @ClementC. the $\cos$ term is alternating between positive and negative, albeit, seemingly random values. The $\sqrt(k)$ term ensures that the series will alternate because it's never a multiple of pi (for integer $k$s). Therefore, $\cos\sqrt k$ is alternating

Comment: That's not what alternating means.

Comment: To apply Leibniz's criterion, you need consecutive terms to be of different sign.  This is not the case here. What you call "alternating" is not what alternating is supposed to mean. @ChristopherMarley

Comment: @anomaly My bad, I clearly wasn't thinking. I forgot about "alternating."

Comment: The derivative of square root goes to 0 so you could possibly approximate with an integral

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948394/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cos-sqrtnn-converge

Comment: @Mark hey man. What do you mean? Can you explain your thoughts a little bit more or maybe provide a link to related theorem?

Comment: @LevonMinasian What I mean is that, for big enough $n$, $\int_n^{n+1} \cos(\sqrt x)  /x dx$ is very close to $\int_n^{n+1} \cos(\sqrt n) / x dx$ so it could be massaged into a bound for the sum

Comment: @LevonMinasian I elaborated here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4038108/4460