# Find limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+n^{\frac{1}{2}}+n^{\frac{1}{3}}+\cdots+n^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$

Tags: limits

How to calculate this limit?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nn^{\frac{1}{k}}}{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n+n^{\frac{1}{2}}+n^{\frac{1}{3}}+\cdots+n^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$$
By computer it seems the limit is $2$. The lower bound is easy. But I don't know how to calculate the upper bound. I have tried Stolz theorem, then we need to estimate
$$c_n=1+(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}+\sum_{k=2}^n((n+1)^{\frac{1}{k}}-n^{\frac{1}{k}})$$
since $k$ is associate to $n$, I failed to estimate $\sum_{k=2}^n((n+1)^{\frac{1}{k}}-n^{\frac{1}{k}})$. Besides, this limit looks like the Riemann sum but I didn't find the form and function. So cound you please give some tips?

Or if there is the same question please share the link, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods to find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nn^{1/k} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307028/methods-to-find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits-k-1nn1-k) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bn%2Bn%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%2Bn%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%7D%2B%5Ccdots%2Bn%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%7D%7Bn%7D%24)

Comment: In particular, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/363748

Comment: A yes. I surf this without "sigma" thus I didn't find this page. so maybe this question can be closed now