# How to calculate the following limit: $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)$?

Tags: limits, radicals

I have to solve a series of limits and I can't find out this one.
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)= \,?$$
I have the feeling that this is equal to $0$, but I don't know how to prove it. Note that it may be a good idea to use $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \sqrt[n]{x}=1$.

Comment: Do you mean $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Yes, I meant when n tends to infinity. sorry.

Comment: See also
[Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n(\sqrt[n]x-1)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1981222)

Answer (score 1):

You may observe that, for any fixed $x>0$, **assuming that** $n \to \infty$, then
$$
\sqrt[n]{x}=e^{1/n\times \log x}=1+O\left( \frac1n\right)
$$ giving
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)=O\left( \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ and the desired limit is equal to $0$.

Comment: @Wojowu I assume the OP means, for any fixed $x$, what is the limit as $n \to \infty$. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: If we assume this is what OP really means, then I agree that this is correct.

Comment: I don't see any $n \to \infty$ in OP

Comment: @EugenCovaci I think there is a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously for any $n>0$,

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)=\infty,$$ so that we infer that the real question is

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{x}-1).$$

Knowing that 
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} n(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)=\ln(x),$$

the limit is $0$.

---

$$n(\sqrt[n]x-1)=y\iff x=\left(1+\frac yn\right)^n.$$