# Evaluate limit to infinity of roots of $n$ [ $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n (\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$ ]

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Here is the problem:

Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n (\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$

At my disposal:

For $ n \ge 1,  n \in \mathbb{N}$ , we have $(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)\le 2/ \sqrt n $

Hence , the upper bound of the expression is  $2$.

I suspect that the limit is $0$.

A hint please for an elementary solution without logs.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please edit your question, where does the first root end?

Comment: Hopefully better now, thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at this question: [How to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{n} - 1) = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73403)