# Evaluating Limit Question $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\ \frac{1+\sqrt[2]{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, radicals

Does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\ \frac{1+\sqrt[2]{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}=1$?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean).

Comment: The sequence n^1/n decreases for n >=3.Your sequence is bigger than n times 1/n since it is the minimal sumand.And this sequence converges to 1. Try to find a bigger sequence that converges also to 1.

Comment: @Anonymous No, the result follows immediately from the theorem in the link (take $a_n=\root n\of n$).  But this may be overkill; see alpha's comment.

Comment: @alpha.Debi:  Please make sure to put in parentheses.  n^1/n=1 because the exponentiation takes precedence.  You are right that n^(1/n) decreases with n starting with 3.

Comment: OK, I was talking about n^(1/n), the general sumand of the numerator of his question.

Comment: @alpha.Debi could you please format your comment above stating: "you can express the sequence as the summ of the two first sumands with the other, and the n-3 other are lower than n-3 times 3^1/3 / n that converges to 3^1/3" in TeX so I can understand which sequence you mean? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See the explanation of David Mitra.What I said is no necessary:AL your sequence is lower than n times (the third sumand) /n.But it does not help because you should find a bigger sequence that converges to 1.That was to explain that the final limit is finit , because you wrote infinite , now I see youwrote 1.

Comment: @David Mitra isn't the limit of $n\cdot 3^{1/n}=\infty$ because $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\ 3^{1/n}=1$ and $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\ n=\infty$?

Comment: @David Mitra how do I show that $\sqrt[k]{k}\le 3^{1\over n}$ for every $1\le k\le n$? (BTW, we haven't gotten to derivations in the course yet).

Comment: in the $n$ numbers $1,\sqrt[2]{2},\sqrt[3]{3},...,\sqrt[n]{n}$ the biggest one is $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

Comment: Yes, blind spot, deleted.

Comment: @Aryabhata Yes, of course. Complete brain freeze on my part. Deleting...

Comment: @David Mitra did you mean $\sqrt[k]{k}\le 3^{1\over n}$ or $\sqrt[k]{k}\le 3^{1\over 3}$? if you meant $3^{1\over 3}$ I can't use the squeeze therorem with that as it doesn't converges to 1.

Comment: THREE answers have been posted, none of them by me, but so far the ONLY up-vote for this question is mine!

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I would have, if it had shown some prior effort.

Comment: @Aryabhata I'm a new student in Math, unfortunately I'm not too advanced as you can see from my questions. However, I'm doing as much as I can before asking questions here, although sometimes it seems to more advanced people that no efforts have been made.

Comment: @Anonymous: You can always mention what approaches you took.

Comment: @Aryabhata in the original post you can see my initial attempt, as this post was edited several times.

Comment: @Anonymous: I see. +1 then. In future, I suggest you leave your working in.

Comment: @Aryabhata I'll certainly keep that in mind for the next times. Thank you very much for your time and efforts.

Comment: By considering $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^x}$, and the partitions $\{0,1/n,\ldots (n-1)/n,1\}$ of $[0,1]$, I was tempted to say that $$\frac{1+\sqrt[2]{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}f(1/k),$$ is a Riemann sum of $f$ over $[0,1]$, so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{k}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^x}dx,$$ but it seems that [$f$ don't have primitives in terms of elementary functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[1%2F%28x^x%29%2Cx]).

Comment: See also: [Computing $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240585)

Comment: Since several answers mentioned this result, it's probably good to add a link to a post where it is also proved: [On Cesàro convergence: If $ x_n \to x $ then $z_n = \frac{x_1 + \dots +x_n}{n} \to x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155839).

Comment: @leo just wanted to point out that your comment here is a bit misleading (I stumbled upon it and it really confused me first). Even if your $f$ did have an antiderivative, it wouldn't help because the limit you have in the LHS is not the one required in the question.

Comment: @SayanDutta it is, it's just I made a mistake. It should be $\sqrt[k]{k}$ instead of $\sqrt[n]{k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $1.$ You can use the following result:
If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }a_n=a$, then we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}=a.$$

And you can prove this result by the definition of limits of sequences. Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1.$

Answer (score 7):

The limit immediately evaluates to $1$ after applying [Stolz-Caesaro.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz-Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

If one wants a more precise estimate, Euler-Maclaurin and $\sqrt[n]{n} = e^{(\log n)/n} $ gives: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt[k]{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+ \frac{\log k}{k} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{\log^2 k}{k^2} \right) \right) = n + \frac{\log^2 n}{2} + \frac{\log n}{2n} + \mathcal{o}\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right).$$

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Comment: Good answer! But I think it is difficult for a beginner!

Comment: @Riemann I agree my answer is perhaps not ideal for a beginner, the squeeze method mentioned in the comments above is probably the simplest. I just thought it would be interesting for the OP and others to see other approaches.

Comment: @Ragib Zaman Yes, of course. I quite agree with you.

Comment: I don't see any valid proof by the squeeze method in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

For a completely elementary proof, you can use the elementary theorem(IMO) that if $a_n \to a$ then $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \to a$ as mentioned in the comments and in the other answers.

We can also do using the squeeze (but I don't see a valid proof in the comments yet).

As in my answer here: [How to show that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n/115825#115825)

By using $\text{AM} \ge \text{GM}$ on $k-2$ ones, $\sqrt{k}$, $\sqrt{k}$ that, for $k \ge 3$,

$$ 1  + \frac{2}{\sqrt{k}} \ge 1 - \frac{2}{k} +\frac{2}{\sqrt{k}} \ge k^{1/k} \ge 1 $$

Now we have that (using the mean value theorem, or otherwise)

$$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}} \lt \sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k} \lt \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$$

Adding gives us that

$$ \sum_{k=3}^{n} \frac{2}{\sqrt{k}} \le 4\sqrt{n} + 2$$

Thus

$$ n + 4\sqrt{n} + 10 \ge \sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/k} \ge n$$

And so

$$1  + \frac{4}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{10}{n} \ge \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/k} \ge 1$$

and now we can apply the squeeze.

Comment: If you don't want to use mean value theorem, $\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k}} \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k}}$

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out your proof. why does $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}} \lt \sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}$?

Comment: @Anonymous: You don't really need that part, but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k}} \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k+1}}$

Comment: OK, that part I understood, but I don't see how it relates to your answer.

Comment: @Anonymous: It does not. It might make it easier to see how the mean value theorem applies though.

Comment: Which inequalities did you add to get $\sum\limits_{k=3}^n\frac2{\sqrt k}\le 4\sqrt n +2$ ? I see the telescoping sum $\sum\limits_{k=3}^n\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k,$ but how did you get $4\sqrt n+2$?

Answer (score 2):

Set $a_n=1+\root 2\of 2+\root3\of 3+\cdots +\root n\of n$.

Here is a proof based on the facts that

$\ \ \ \ \ $1) $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \root n\of n=1$

and

$\ \ \ \ \ \ $2) $(\root n\of n)$ is decreasing for $n\ge3$.

Trivially, ${a_n\over n}\ge 1$ for all $n$; thus,
$$\tag{1}
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n\over n}\ge 1.
$$

By 2), we have for a fixed $M\ge 3$  and $k$ a positive integer:

$$\eqalign{
{a_{M+k}\over M+k}
\ \ &\ \ ={a_M\over M+k}+{ (M+1)^{1/M+1} + (M+2)^{1/M+2}+\cdots+(M+k)^{M+k}\over M+k }\cr
\ \ &\ \ \le  {a_M\over M+k}+{ k(M+1)^{1/M+1} \over M+k}\cr
 & \buildrel{ k\rightarrow\infty}\over\longrightarrow \ \ 0+{(M+1)^{M+1}}.\phantom{M\over M}
}
$$
From this it follows that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_n\over n}\le (M+1)^{1/M+1}$ for all $M\ge3$; and, thus by 1), we have  $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_n\over n}\le1$. Combining this result with $(1)$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty }{a_n\over n}=1$.

This is just a modification of the proof of the Cesaro  theorem found [here](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/sequence/hardlim/hardlim.html).
The decreasing condition 2) used in the above is not needed, and, alternatively, you could just use the proof in the link.