# Show that: $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{n}=0 $

Tags: limits

Here is an exercise:

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence such that $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}(x_n-x_{n-2})=0$. 
Show that:

$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{n}=0 $$

Thanks.

Comment: There is a limit missing there.

Comment: Thinking that a limit is missing, you can apply the Cesaro-Stolz theorem.

Comment: How could I apply the Cesaro-Stolz theorem?

Comment: See my answer. Telescoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Let $y_n=|x_n-x_{n-1}|$. Note that $|y_n-y_{n-1}|\le |x_n-x_{n-2}|$. Then 
$$
|\frac {x_n-x_{n-1}}{n}|=\frac{y_n}{n} \le \frac{|y_n-y_{n-1}|+|y_{n-1}-y_{n-2}|+\dots+|y_{N+1}-y_N|}{n}+\frac{y_N}{n}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Given a sequence $\langle x_n\rangle $ denote $\Delta x_n=x_{n+1}-x_n$.

Let $$a_n=x_n-x_{n-2}$$

Then $a_n\to 0$ and $a_{n+1}\to 0$ so $$\omega_n =a_{n+1}-a_n\to 0$$ Note that $\omega_n=\Delta x_{n}-\Delta x_{n-1}$

[By Cesàro](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn-to-x/411588#411588),

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\omega_k=0$$

What is the above?

Comment: What is the Cesaro? I cannot find it in the link.

Comment: @Simple I am linking to a proof of the following: If $a_n\to \ell$ then $$\frac 1 n\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\to \ell$$ too. This is usually called "Cesàros Theorem" in honor to [Ernesto Cesàro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernesto_Ces%C3%A0ro)

Comment: @Sanchez True. It has some "remainders", but they should be killed off by the $n^{-1}$.