# Limit of $(s_1 + \ldots + s_n)/n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $\sigma_n = \frac{1}{n}(s_1 + \ldots + s_n)$. Assuming that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = s$, prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sigma_n = s$.

How do I start with this proof? It makes intuitive sense, but I don't know how to do it formally. I've tried writing down the definition of the limit but have not gotten very far, so some hints would help. Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn-to-x

Comment: Could you do it if $s_n =s$ for $n\ge 10^6?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This falls into a standard pattern
where there are bad parts
and good parts.

In this case,
for any $\epsilon > 0$,
there is a
$N(\epsilon)$
such that
$|s_n - s| < \epsilon$
for
$n \ge N(\epsilon)$.
This is the good part.

The bad part  has
the other $n$,
for which you might have
$|s_n - s| \ge \epsilon$.

Write

$\begin{array}\\
S(n)
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k}{n}\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(\epsilon)-1} s_k}{n}
+\dfrac{\sum_{k=N(\epsilon)}^{n} s_k}{n}\\
\text{so that}\\
S(n)-s
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k}{n}-s\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} (s_k-s)}{n}\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(\epsilon)-1} (s_k-s)}{n}
+\dfrac{\sum_{k=N(\epsilon)}^{n} (s_k-s)}{n}\\
&=D_1+D_2\\
\end{array}
$

We want to show that
$S(n)-s$
can be made as small
as we want.

$D_1$ has the bad part,
where the $s_k$ might be
far from $s$.

$D_2$ has the good part,
where all the
$s_k$ are close to $s$.
For this,
we immediately have
$|D_2| < \epsilon$
since each
$|s_k-s| < \epsilon$.

If we can make
$|D_1| < \epsilon$,
then 
$S(n) - s|
< 2\epsilon$,
and we are done.
Note that it doesn't matter that
we have $2\epsilon$
instead of $\epsilon$.

We can do this
by making $n$ large.

Let
$d(\epsilon)
=\max_{k=1}^{N(\epsilon)-1} |s_k-s|
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
|D_1|
&=\big|\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(\epsilon)-1} (s_k-s)}{n}\big|\\
&\le\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(\epsilon)-1} |s_k-s|}{n}\\
&\le\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N(\epsilon)-1} d(\epsilon)}{n}\\
&\le\dfrac{N(\epsilon) d(\epsilon)}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$\dfrac{N(\epsilon) d(\epsilon)}{n}
< \epsilon$,
or
$n > \dfrac{N(\epsilon) d(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}
$,
$|D_1| < \epsilon$,
which is want we want.

None of this is original.
This is standard,
and a good thing to know.