# Prove $b_n := \frac1n * \sum_\limits{k=1}^n a_k$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following sequence :

$$b_n := \frac1n * \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$

and I want to prove that this sequence converges. I know that the sequence $a_n$ converges already. I am not quite sure however where to start with the proof. For example: How do I prove that atleast the sum of a convergent sequence converges again? Maybe by using cauchy sequences? I am a bit lost so any hint/help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: The question has been posted numerous times here, so search for a duplicate.

Comment: you might start with witing $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_{n+1}-b_n$ as series and then consider the summands $b_{n+1}-b_n$. i did not check weather this works, it might or might not help.

Comment: i messed up the indices, sorry for that. the summands on the right hand side must of course be indiced by $k$ and $k+1$ instead of $n$ and $n+1$

Comment: A very similar question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn-to-x). The difference is that the linked question already assume that the Césaro sum will converge to the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as **Cauchy's First Theorem on Limits**:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n<\infty\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n}{n}<\infty$

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n\to0$ then for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an $M$ such that $\lvert a_k\rvert<\varepsilon$ for all $k>M$.  This implies $$-\varepsilon\leftarrow\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^M a_k -\varepsilon<\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^M a_k -\frac{\varepsilon(n-M)}{n}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^M a_k -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=M+1}^n \varepsilon<b_n<\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^M a_k +\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=M+1}^n \varepsilon= \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^M a_k +\frac{\varepsilon(n-M)}{n}<\varepsilon+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^M a_k\to\varepsilon,$$and since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, the squeeze theorem yields $b_n\to0$.

If $a_n\to A\ne0$, it is eventually positive or negative. Hence $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is eventually monotone increasing to $+\infty$ or monotone decreasing to $-\infty$. This means we can apply the Stolz-Cesàro theorem, which gives that $b_n$ has the same limit as $a_n$.