# Limit of a sequence related to Cesaro sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A question related to the post : [On Cesaro convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-cesaro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn).

Let $(a_n)$ an *increasing* sequence of non-negative real numbers and let $(S_n)$ defined by $$S_n=\frac 1 n\sum_{k=1}^n  a_k.$$

Is it true that if $(S_n)$ converges to $L$ as $n \to \infty$ also $(a_n)$ converges to $L$ ?

In the linked post, it is asserted that - in general - this is not true [see Pedro's ansewer, last line : **COR** If $\lim a_n$ exists and equals $\ell$, so does $\lim S_n$, and it also equals $\ell$. The converse is not true.]

But I suppose that in the case above the "trick" can be that the convergence of $S_n$ impose that $a_n$ is bounded. Is it correct ?

May I have a proof (or a counterexample) ?

Comment: You can use that an increasing sequence has a limit (eventually $+\infty$), and Cesaro's theorem is true also for a sequence converging to $+\infty$.

Comment: What I say is that as $a_n$ is increasing, then $a_n\to l$ (with $l=+\infty$ allowed). But then $S_n\to l$ by Cesaro's theorem (it is true also for $l=+\infty$). It is easy to finish.

Comment: Your hypothesis is that $S_n\to L$. By my previous comment, $S_n\to l$. Hence $L=l$, and $a_n\to L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using that $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing and non-negative, we get that
$$\frac{a_n}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=n}^{2n} a_k \leq S_{2n}.$$
Thus, $S_{2n} \rightarrow L$ already implies that $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and thus convergent (because it is a increasing sequence). Let $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_k = a$, then we know that the Cesaro mean convergences already to $a$, i.e.
$$L= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n =a,$$
i.e. $a=L$ as claimed.