# To prove that $y_n $ converges

Tags: real-analysis

Given $x_n$ is convergent sequence with limit eqals to $a$. to prove that

$y_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n}{n}$ converges to same limit

Now $$\left|\frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n}{n} - a \right|\\=\left|\frac{(x_1 - a) + (x_2-a) + ... + (x_n-a)}{n}\right |$$

Since $x_n$ is convergent. so it is bounded. so for all $n$

$x_n \leq M + a$

I am not sure how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155839/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2858957/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193157/42969

Comment: Look up “cesaro mean convergence proof” – this has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: @MartinRi am confused if numerator has n terms or infinite terms..i mean is $x_{n+1}$ part of numerator ?

Comment: Every numerator has finitely many terms: $y_1 = x_1$, $y_2 = (x_1+x_2)/2$, $y_3 = (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)/3$, ...

Comment: @MartinR but $y_n$ are infinite, no ?

Comment: Of course there are infinitely many $y_n$, but each $y_n$ is the sum of finitely many $x_n$. Where is the problem?

Comment: Your equality shows we really only need to show if $x_n\to0,$ then the means converge to $0.$

Comment: So when $x_n\to0,$ we have that all $|x_i|<M$ for some $M,$ and for $i$ large, $|x_i|$ is small. So you need "enough" of the small terms to outweigh the terms we know are only bounded. So, find $N$ such that $|x_i|<\epsilon/2$ for $i>N.$ Then for $n>N$ we have $$|y_n|\leq \frac{NM}{n}+\frac\epsilon 2\frac{n-N}{n}\leq \frac\epsilon2+\frac{MN}n.$$ So you need $$\frac{NM}{n}<\frac\epsilon2$$ or $$n>\frac{2MN}{\epsilon}.$$ Set $N'=\max(N,2MN/\epsilon)$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equality shows that we can restrict to the case when $x_n\to0,$ since, if $x_n\to a,$ we can solve the problem for $z_n=x_n-a\to0.$

So when $x_n\to0,$ we have that there exists an $M$ such that all $|x_i|<M,$ and for $i$ large, $|x_i|$ is small.

So you need "enough" of the small terms to outweigh the terms we know are only bounded.

So, find $N$ such that $|x_i|<\epsilon/2$ for $i>N.$ Then for $n>N$ we have $$\begin{align}|y_n|&\leq \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^N|x_i|+\frac1n\sum_{i=N+1}^n|x_i|\\
&\leq\frac{NM}{n}+\frac\epsilon 2\frac{n-N}{n}\\
&\leq \frac\epsilon2+\frac{MN}n.\end{align} $$

So you need $$\frac{NM}{n}<\frac\epsilon2$$ or $$n>\frac{2MN}{\epsilon}.$$

Set $N'=\max(N,2MN/\epsilon)$ and then for $n>N',$ $|y_n|<\epsilon.$

Essentially, $N$ determines that the first $N$ terms are merely known to be bounded, and any terms after these are "small." Then $MN/\epsilon$ defines what it means for "enough terms to be small" for the small terms to outweigh those first $N$ terms.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/155839. Is it really necessary to post another proof?

Comment: I hated to see the wrong answer as the only answer. @MartinR Initially, I was content to put it in comments.

Comment: But made my answer community wiki to ensure I'm not just gaming the system.

Comment: maybe $|x_i| < \frac {\epsilon} { 2} $ for $i \geq  n+1$...so what to do then

Comment: Don't confusing $n$ and $N.$ Different variables. I have written more after that step, what didn't you follow? Be specific. @Olivia

Comment: @ThomasAndrews why you split the n terms into two pieces (is it because boundedness alone wont solve it ?) ? and how to split them if the $x_i$ is less than epsilon for very large value which cross n. like example sequence x_n lies in epsilon neighbourhood for value more than n, say n+9 and is the little n the original n which is to be found for given epsilon ?

Comment: Specifically, $N$ is a fixed single value, depending on the sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\epsilon.$

Comment: yes but y_n has n terms of x_n only and not infinite.

Comment: As I said at the beginning and end, you need enough small terms to outweigh the terms we only know are bounded. So you want to split the terms into "known to be small" and "not-known to be small." Luckily, $x_n\to0$ means we can make a cut-off that lets us say "every term after this is small."

Comment: Who said anything about infinite terms? @Olivia

Comment: but all terms are bounded anyhow i.e smaller than something. so what is known to be small and not known to be small

Comment: if we assume this at start $x_i < \epsilon  $ for $n> n+1, n+2,n+3... $

Comment: $n>n+1?$ When is it possible for $n>n+1?$ $n>N.$ Don't mistake the $n$ and $N.$ @Olivia I have no idea what you are getting at in that comment.

Comment: You are correct, being bounded is not enough. The whole point is that being bounded is not enough, that we can cut off and consider some finite number of $x_i$ as potentially problematic, and make the number of terms which aren't problematic large enough to outweigh the problematic ones. @Olivia

Comment: An example would be $x_k=\frac1k$ and $\epsilon=\frac14.$ Then we can choose $M=1, N=8.$ and we conclude that if $n>2MN/epsilon=64,$ then $$|y_n|=\frac{1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n}{n}<\frac14.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews one thing i was doubt is that if tail of  x_n starts after i > n then what to do ? because we have assumed that tail starts from somewhere at N+1.

Comment: You've confused $n$ with $N,$ again. There is an $N$ such that $|x_i|<\epsilon/2$ for $i>N,$ by the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0.$ If we don't know $x_n\to 0,$ we don't have the rest of the proof. Maybe you are confused by the phrase $x_n\to0?$ It is just a shorthand for $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0.$