# Arithmetic mean sequence, is this proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $a_n\to a\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\frac{a_1+\cdots + a_n}{n}\to a$

I start by proving the case $a_n\to 0$ then I know how to generalize to the case $a\in\mathbb{R}$ (my aim here is more to be sure that this type of reasoning below is correct, rather than answering this especific question).

Given $\epsilon>0$ choose $N$ such that $n>N \implies |a_n|<\epsilon /2$. **After that $N$ chosen, choose $N_0$ such that** $N_0 > \frac{2|a_1 + \cdots + a_N|}{\epsilon}$.

Then $n > \max\{N, N_0\}$ implies
$$
\left|\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}\right| \le  \left|\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_N}{n}\right| + \left|\frac{a_{N+1} + \cdots + a_n}{n}\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon
$$
Then $\left|\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}\right|\to 0$

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your proof for sure is not correct.

Comment: @DeepSea can you please explain why?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-ces%c3%a0ro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn) and the ones linked to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a couple more steps in, but the idea is correct.  You have not shown how $N,N_0$ come into it.  I would write
$$\begin {align}\left|\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}\right| &\le  \left|\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_N}{n}\right| + \left|\frac{a_{N+1} + \cdots + a_n}{n}\right| \\
&\le  \left|\frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_N}{N_0}\right| + \left|\frac{(n-N+1)\frac \epsilon 2}{n}\right|\\
&\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\&= \epsilon \end {align}$$