# How to show that for any real numbers $\{a_n\}$ if $a_n\to 0$, then $\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}\to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to show that for any real numbers $\{a_n\}$ if $a_n\to 0$, then $\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}
{n}\to 0$.

I am a beginner to learn real analysis. Can any one give some suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Eventually they will all be less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On Cesàro convergence: If $ x_n \to x $ then $ z_n = \frac{x_1 + \dots +x_n}{n} \to x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-ces%c3%a0ro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn)