# What is mutual information of a Markov chain?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, information-theory

I am working on the following exercise:

> Below is the transition graph of a Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ where each edge is bi-directional . For each vertex, the probabilities of the out-going edges are uniformly distributed, e.g. the probability of moving from 1 to 3 is 1/4 and from 2 to 5 is 1/3 .
>
> a) Find the stationary distribution.
>
> b) Compute the entropy rate of the stationary Markov chain.
>
> c) Compute the mutual information $I(X_n; X_{n−1})$ assuming the process is stationary.

[image]

My attempt:

a) The first thing I did was writing down the transition matrix $P$ as:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
&0 &1/4 &1/4 &1/4 &1/4 \\
&1/3 &0 &1/3 &0 &1/3  \\
&1/3 &1/3 &0 &1/3 &0 \\
&1/3 &0 &1/3 &0 &1/3 \\
&1/3 &1/3 &0 &1/3 &0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And I computed the stionary distribution $\nu$ as the left eigenvector of $1$ from $P$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0.5547    &0.4160    &0.4160    &0.4160    &0.4160
\end{bmatrix}.$$

b) For the entropy rate I would just use the formula

$$-\sum_{x,y \in \mathcal{X}} \nu(x) \  p(y \mid x) \ \log_2(p(y \mid x)).$$

c) I do not know what to do here. What should "stationarity" help in computing mutual information? Could you explain this point to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the Markov chain reaches the stationary state, the probability distribution keeps changing, so a time-invariant mutual information does not make sense. That is, you can't find an expression to just plug in a value of $n$ and get the mutual information.

Let $\pi = \{\pi_i\}_{i=1}^5$ denote the stationary distribution. Then,
\begin{align*}
I(X_n; X_{n-1}) &= H(X_n) - H(X_n|X_{n-1}) = H(\pi) - H(X_n|X_{n-1})
\end{align*}

$H(\pi)$ is easy to compute, so we just need to figure out how to deal with the second term. Luckily, that's already done in the previous part. Letting $H(\mathcal{X})$ denote the entropy rate of the chain, here is a quick derivation:
\begin{align*}
H(\mathcal{X}) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}H(X_1,...,X_n) \\
&=^{(1)} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n H(X_i|X_{i-1},...,X_1) \\
&=^{(2)} \lim_{n\to \infty} H(X_n|X_{n-1},...,X_1) \\
&=^{(3)} \lim_{n\to\infty} H(X_n|X_{n-1}) \\
&=^{(4)} H(X_n|X_{n-1})
\end{align*}

(1) By Chain Rule, (2) [By Cesàro convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-ces%c3%a0ro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn), (3) By Markovianity, (4) By stationarity, i.e. since the distribution has already converged to its limit, so has this expression.

Putting it all together, 
$$I(X_n; X_{n-1}) = H(\pi) - H(\mathcal{X}).$$