# Given $a_n$ converges to $a$ how to find this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, means

> If the terms of a sequence $a_n$ converge to $a$, show that $\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$ also converges to $a$. Also show that the converse isn't necessarily true.

Please help me with this- I am unable to approach this problem, and don't even know where to begin looking for a solution.

Comment: For the second part $a_k=(-1)^k$ works

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-cesàro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Just remind that if $a_n$ converges to $a$, as of a certain $N$, the terms $a_n$ remain at distance at most $\epsilon$ of $a$. Now if you take the average, you will have a finite number of terms with arbitrary values, but an infinity of them at distance $\epsilon$ or less. So with sufficiently many terms, the average will stay close to $a$.