# Given a ergodic Markov chain find the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log{P}(\omega_{i} \neq 1)}{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose we have an ergodic Markov chain on a finite state space $X=\{1,2, \ldots, r\}$ with transition matrix $A$ and stationary measure $\pi$ which we also take to be the initial distribution. I wanted the find the following limit:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(P\{\omega_{i} \neq 1: i=0,1,2 \ldots, n \}, )}{n}$$

I'm honestly quite lost on how to go about this, it seems like law of large numbers for Markov chains should be relevant.

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? maybe you meant to sum up some probabilities? Anyway, you might find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-ces%c3%a0ro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn helpful

Comment: Given the assumptions that the chain is ergodic and stationary (and on a finite state space, no less), it should be clear to see that the probability of a state never being visited is zero. So in fact the numerator in your expression has limit zero with probability one - which of course implies the same when divided by $n$.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you mean by the event $\{\omega_i\not = 1: i=0,1,2, \ldots,n\}$. Is it to be
$$
\cap_{i=0}^n\{\omega: \omega_i\not=1\}
$$
or something else?

Comment: My guess is you are missing a log in the numerator. If you include a log, the  limit can be computed using the spectral decomposition of the chain.

Comment: @YuvalPeres, thank you, yes, I forgot the log in the numerator. Does spectral decomposition, here apply to the transition matrix?

Comment: @JohnDawkins, The way I read it was the probability that a sample path $\omega$ doesn't visit state $1$, so I believe that is the intersection of sets you wrote.

Comment: Yes, to analyze high powers of the transition matrix diagonalize it if possible, otherwise consider the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be the substochastic matrix obtained from the transition matrix $P$ by erasing the first row and column, and let $\lambda(M)<1$ denote its Perron eigenvalue [1]. The probability in the numerator of the question is $\pi M^n {\bf 1}$ where ${\bf 1}$ is the all ones vector. Thus
$$\lim_n \frac {\log(\pi M^n {\bf 1})}{n} =\log \lambda(M)<0 \,.
$$

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

Comment: Thank you Professor! I follow now, $\pi$ is the left eigenvector for $\lambda$ whose coefficients sum to one.

Comment: $\pi$  need not be a left eigenvector of $M$ but $\pi \ge c \cdot v$ where $v$ is the left Perron eigenvector and $c$ is a scalar. That suffices, see the Perron Frobenius Theorem.

Comment: I see. $v$ is positive and guaranteed by the Perron Frobenius Theorem. But how does the inequality suffice in showing ${\pi}M^{n}\textbf{1} \sim \lambda(M)^{n}$. Sorry for the persistent bugging.

Comment: The inequality $\pi \ge cv$  suffices because we are looking at the logarithm. recall also the Gelfand formula for the spectral radius that applies in complete geenrality $\|M^k\|^{1/k} \to \lambda(M)$ as $ k \to \infty$.