# if $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k=0$, with $a_k \geq 0$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n a_k =0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I need help to prove the question or find a counterexample. I think that was true. Proof idea:
Since  $\lim_{k\to \infty} a_k=0$, given $\epsilon >0$ there is $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k < \epsilon$ for all $k > k_0$. Then for $n>k_0$,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n a_k =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{k_0} a_k+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=k_0+1}^n a_k <\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{k_0-1} a_k+\frac{n-k_0}{n} \epsilon
$$
so
$$
 \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n a_k <\epsilon,
$$
and hence the proof is completed.

Comment: Assume the average value is nonzero.

Comment: You want to use $\leq$ instead of $<$. Note that if a function is nonnegative its limit is not necessarily nonnegative.  If you really want to be rigorous you can show the $\limsup$ is less than or equal to $\epsilon$, but your work is basically doing the right thing.

Comment: The idea is basically correct, but you're mixing up $\varepsilon$-$\delta_{\varepsilon}$ definition and the use of the comparison theorem; I would use the fact that, since for any fixed $\varepsilon>0$ and any fixed $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence $(a_j)_j =\frac{j-k_0}{j}\varepsilon$ tends to $\varepsilon$ as $j \to \infty$, you can get the estimation you've already obtained.

Comment: i forget to assume that $a_k\geq0$. thanks for the answer

Comment: @EmanuelRamadori: You're welcome, it is preferred to edit your questions instead of making corrections in the comments; you can use the option "edit" under your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I already updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x_n) \to 0$ then
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n}{n}=0$

[Please see this to get a proof of Cesaro convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-ces%C3%A0ro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn)