# Prove $F_n$ converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continous functions which converges
> uniformly on $[a, b]$ to a function $f$.
>
> Define:
>
> $F_n(x) = \frac{f_1(x) + f_2(x)+...+f_n(x)}{n}$.
>
> Prove:
>
> $F_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Im not so sure how to approach the question.

Any attempts to use Weierstrass M-test failed.

How can i continue?

Hints will be appericiated.

Comment: Hint: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155839/42969