# Convergence of Cesaro mean - is this proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I've been trying to prove the following proposition:
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_n\right)=0\:\:\rightarrow \:\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}\right)=0$$

This is a proof sketch, about which I feel a bit uncertain:

$$\left|\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}-0\right|=\left|\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}\right|=\frac{\left|x_1+x_2+...+x_n\right|}{n}$$
**Applying the triangle inequality:**

$$\frac{\left|x_1+x_2+...+x_n\right|}{n}\:\le _{ }\:\frac{\left|x_1\right|+\left|x_2\right|+...+\left|x_n\right|}{n}$$
**$x_n$ is bounded, thus there exists some $M>0$ such that $\left|x_n\right|<M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and therefore:**
$$\frac{\left|x_1\right|+\left|x_2\right|+...+\left|x_n\right|}{n}\le _{\:\:}\frac{\left(n-1\right)M\:+\left|x_n\right|}{n}\:\le M\:+\frac{\left|x_n\right|}{n}\le M+\left|x_n\right|$$

**$x_n\rightarrow 0,\:$thus$\:\forall \:\left(ϵ-M\right)\:>0,\:\:\exists \:N\in \mathbb{R}\:$such that$\:\left|x_n\right|<ϵ-M$, and therefore:**

$$\left|\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}\right|<...<M\:+\left|x_n\right|<ϵ$$

I'd be really glad for reviews and corrections if I've had any mistakes somewhere, it would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: That would only apply for when $\epsilon>M,$ and you need to prove it for all $\epsilon>0.$ So this doesn't work.

Comment: Basically, you need a *lot* of small terms in the numerator to balance out the terms that are closer to $M.$

Comment: Try to break down the sum in the numerator into two pieces: one whose contribution is small because of the denominator $n\to\infty$ and another one whose contribution is small because the addends are small.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-ces%c3%a0ro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn-to