# Proving $x^{1/x}$ approaches $1$ as $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying to solve a question that was uploaded here ([Computing $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240585/computing-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1-sqrt2-sqrt33-cdots-sqrt)):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac  {1 + 2^{1/2} + 3^{1/3} +...+ x^{1/x}}{x}$$

So i used the identity $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/x} = 1$$ and tried to prove it myself.

Since $$(\sqrt[x]{x})^x = x\implies f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x} =  \frac x{(\sqrt[x]{x})^{x-1}}$$

I tried to prove that there is a horizontal asymptote at $y=1$ when $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x$ using the latter function without using L'Hôpital's rule.
I want to emphasize that I am not currently trying to solve the first limit, but trying to prove the asymptote of the function $f(x)$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the question? If it is in your title then this is [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115822/11619).

Comment: Your idea seems to be a good approach, namely that once you know $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n} = 1$, the more elaborate limit treated in the linked Question becomes a straightforward consequence.  Perhaps you are having difficulty carrying through this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$x^\frac1x=e^{\frac{\log x}{x}}\to 1$$

indeed by standard limit

$$\frac{\log x}{x}\to 0$$

To prove the latter set $x=e^y$ with $y\to \infty$ then

$$\frac{\log x}{x}=\frac{\log e^y}{e^y}=\frac{y}{e^y}\to 0$$

which is true since eventually $e^y\ge y^2$ (can be proved by induction) and then

$$0\le \frac{y}{e^y}\le \frac{y}{y^2}\le \frac1y \to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

You may rty *ab oveo* if you like:

For any $\epsilon>0$ and $n\in\Bbb N$, we have $(1+\epsilon)^n\ge 1 + n\epsilon+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\epsilon^2$. This is $>n+1 $ as soon as $n>\frac2{\epsilon^2}+1$.
Hence $1<(n+1)^{1/n}<1+\epsilon$ for all $n>\frac2{\epsilon^2}+1$.
Then for all $x>\frac2{\epsilon^2}+2$, we find $ n\in \Bbb N$ with $n\le x<n+1$ and $n>\frac2{\epsilon^2}+1$. We conclude that for such $x$,
$$ 1\le x^{1/x}\le(n+1)^{1/n}<1+\epsilon.$$
Therefore,
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}=1.$$