# Limit of $\frac1n\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt[n]{2}}+\frac1{\sqrt[n]{3}}+\dotsb+\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right)$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: analysis, limits, radicals

> Calculate this limit
>   $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{3}}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right).$$

I think inside the parentheses, each limit is $1$, and there are $n$ of them, so their sum is limited to $n$. Also,

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0.$$

Therefore I think,
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{3}}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right) = 0.$$

Is this solution correct? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Hi, please *always* include some English words in the title, so that on right-clicking the title, the usual context menu will not be overridden by MathJax's menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the limit is $1$ because $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ and 
$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\leqslant1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{3}}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\leqslant n.
$$
Note that your approach would also yield the limit $0$ for the sequence
$$
\frac1n\cdot\left(1+1+\cdots+1\right),
$$
for every number of terms in the parenthesis.

Comment: you write very fast i was just about to post the answer, nevertheless nice.

Comment: How about a more tricky question: instead of 1/2^(1/n) + 1/3^(1/n) + … we have 1/2^(1/2) + 1/3^(1/3) + … then all the values would not tend to 1 :)! Also, what can be said about having the harmonic series in the brackets (so 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4), will that simply tend to 0?

Comment: @Just_a_fool Unsurprisingly, different settings might require different methods. But we knew that beforehand, didn't we?

Comment: I'll add a link to the post about limit of $\sqrt[n]n$ (which is used here): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n = \dfrac{1}{n^{1/n}}$, then you can show : $x_n \to 1$ by various means, then apply Cesaro theorem to get the limit $1$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then by applying Stolz-Cesaro theorem we would get limit of slightly different expression:
$\frac1n\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt[2]{2}}+\frac1{\sqrt[3]{3}}+\dotsb+\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Cezàro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean)
the desired limit is equal to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}=1$$

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then by applying Stolz-Cesaro theorem we would get limit of slightly different expression:
$\frac1n\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt[2]{2}}+\frac1{\sqrt[3]{3}}+\dotsb+\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right)$.