# Why is the radius convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$ is $1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Why is the radius convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$ is $1$?

We know that

$$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n] {\frac{1}{4n+1}} = 0$$

And therefore, $R=\infty$. Why is it wrong?

Comment: Have you carried out the Ratio Test to calculate the ROC?

Comment: Not sure what ROC is, but I used Cauchy–Hadamard theorem

Comment: ROC is Radius of Convergence. You gt that by calculating the IOC (=Interval of Convergence) through the Ratio test

Comment: But isn't the formula I used acceptable as well?

Comment: $n^{1/n}$ tends to $1$ as $n\to \infty$, not to $\infty$.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PowerSeries.aspx

Comment: @HansLundmark, could you please demonstrate how is it $1$ and not $0$?

Comment: It should be in your calculus textbook. ;-) But it has of course also been asked many times at this site, for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873290/limit-of-n-th-root-of-1-n

Comment: Or here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\dfrac{\frac{x^{4(n+1)+1}}{4(n+1)+1}}{\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}}\to_{n\to\infty}x^3$ hence the radius of convergence is $1$.

By the way, $\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n] {\frac{1}{4n+1}} = \color{red}1$ :

$\left(\frac{1}n\right)^{1/n}=e^{\ln(1/n)/n}=e^{-\ln(n)/n}$ and $\ln(n)/n\to_{n\infty}0$

Comment: Could you please explain why is the last claim at your answer holds?

Comment: @AlonAlon see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Note that the coefficient of the power series is $\frac1m$ whenever $m\equiv1\pmod4$, and $0$ otherwise, so using the Iverson bracket it can be written $\frac1m[m\equiv1\pmod4]$. Then what you should want to compute is 
$$
 \limsup_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[m]{\frac{[m\equiv1\pmod4]}m}=
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n] {\frac1n}
 =\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-\ln n}n\right)
 =\exp(0)=1,
$$
(since the growth of $n$ beats that of $\ln n$ as $n\to\infty$). This explains your error.