# prove the limit of $k^{1/k}$ is $1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to prove that the limit of the sequence $k^{1/k}$ is $1$ as $k$ tends to infinity without using advanced rules such as L'Hospital's Rule and just using the basic rules in real analysis. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hint: consider $x^{1/x}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ and $x \rightarrow \infty$. Write $x^{1/x} = e^{(1/x)\log x}.$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the sequence   $\ \ x_k = k^{\frac1k} - 1 \geq 0$

$k ^{\frac1k} \to 1 \iff x_k \to 0 \ as\ k \to \infty $

Now, $\ k = (1 + x_k)^k$

Apply binomial theorem :
$$(1+x_k)^k = 1 + kx_k + \frac{(k)(k-1)}{2}x_k^2 + \ ... \ + x_k^k  = k$$

Remove all the extra positive terms except $\frac{(k)(k-1)}{2}x_k^2$ and convert it into an inequality

$$ 0 \leq \frac{(k)(k-1)x_k^2}{2} < k^{\frac1k}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ for \ k > 1$$

So
$$0 \leq x_k^2 < \frac2{k-1}$$

$$ 0 \leq x_k < \sqrt{\frac2{k-1}}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ since  \ \ x_k \geq 0$$
Now apply squeeze theorem, $ x_k \to 0 \ as \ \ k \to \infty  $

Comment: I don't quite understand how to get that inequality from applying the binomial theorem.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: How does one say $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ $>1$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Let $y(k)=k^{\frac1k}$. Then $\ln y=\frac1k \ln k$. So we just compute the limit of $\frac1k \ln k$. Let $t=\ln k$, then $\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac1k \ln k=\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t}{e^t}$.