# Determine if the sequence an = ln(n)/(n^(1/n)) is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have some difficulty with showing that the sequence
$$
a_n = \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{1/n}}
$$
 is divergent. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the behavior of the terms $a_n$ as $n\to\infty$? What kind of tests/ checks/ heuristics do you have for whether series converge or diverge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we can observe that $n^{1/n}\to1$. In fact $n^{1/n}=e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}$ and $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\to0$.

Therefore the denominator tends to $1$ while the numerator tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: @OinkOink You can learn about the limit of $n^{1/n}$ for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1