# Does this series diverge or converge and what to do with (-1)^n

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Can you show the steps followed for proving divergence or convergence

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} $ $\sqrt[n]{n+(-1)^n}$

thankkss

Comment: can i  consider (-1)^n negligible at infinity and what test to choose for such series?

Comment: When proving divergence/convergence, it's useful to bound the summands by something simpler. To deal with the $(-1)^n$, can you think of simple lower and upper bounds for $\sqrt[n]{n+(-1)^n}$?

Comment: in this case you can indeed skip the $(-1)^n$ part, to see this use the sandwich lemma. You always have to make sure that something is negligible in the limit, it won't work in general

Comment: Knowing limit of $\sqrt[n]n$ might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This series clearly diverges (or converges to infinity) since the necessary condition, that in 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+(-1)^n}
$$ 
the sequence $a_n$ is a zero-sequence, i.e. that $a_n\to 0$, is not fulfilled. Since 
$$
\sqrt[n]{n-1}\leq\sqrt[n]{n+(-1)^n}\leq\sqrt[n]{n+1}
$$ 
and 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}=1
$$

Answer (score 3):

No because

$$ \sqrt[n]{n+(-1)^n}\rightarrow 1\neq 0.$$ You know that necessary condition(but not sufficient) for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n<\infty$ is $a_n\rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$n-1 \leq n+(-1)^n \leq n+1$

Comment: yess the sandwich theorem thanksss

Comment: @jammah: Yes. Please note that the $n$th square of each term is larger than $1$, hence the infinite series diverges.

Comment: but is the nth root of n-1 and n+1  =1 ?

Comment: @jammah: Does the comment above not answer your question?

Comment: yess but how do i prove it ?

Comment: @jammah: A positive root of a positive number larger than $1$ is always larger than $1$.

Comment: after this step i do the nth root for each  but isnt the nth root of n-1 <1 and the nth root of n+1 greater than 1 ?

Comment: @jammah: Does the comment above not answer your question?

Comment: hahahahahaha sryyy having bad connection thanksss alottt

Comment: @jammah: You're welcome :)