# lim-how to write it down correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, radicals

I want to show that

$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n}=1$

I know why it is $1$. Cause $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ But how can I write that correct?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n!)^{1/n} \not=1$ even though $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1)

Answer (score 3):

For large enough $n,$

$$0 <\ln (n)<\sqrt {n} $$

$$0 <\ln (n^\frac 1n)<\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}} $$

thus
$$e^0 <n^\frac 1n <e^\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}} $$

and squeeze.

Comment: Readers whose background is on par with the OP will probably appreciate details for your first inequality, e.g. *how large* do we need $n$ to be and what proof-sketch you have in mind.  (After all both $\ln x$ and $\sqrt x$ are convex down as $x\to \infty$.)

Answer (score 1):

$$n^{1/n}=e^{ln(n)/n} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}e^{0}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to notice that the exponent is going to zero. If the base of the exponentiation is going to infinity, the limit may fail to be one. For example, $(n^n)^{1/n}$ goes to infinity, even though the exponent goes to zero.

In your case, however, you are right, the limit is one. To compute it, use l'Hôpital's on the exponential indeterminate form, by first taking the logarithm.

In detail, if $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}$, then 
$$\log L = \log(\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n^{1/n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n},$$
the latter fraction is seen to be an $\infty/\infty$ indeterminate form, which meets the criteria for l'Hôpital's method. So then taking derivatives

$$\log L = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/n}{1}\to 0.$$

Thus we have that $\log L=0,$ or $L=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $$1<\sqrt[n]{n}<1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}$$ and use the sandwich.

Comment: The required proof will probably be a heavy lift for the OP, judging from the simple approach they took to the problem.