# show with convergence test that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)p^n$ converges if $|p|<1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

Using one of the following tests: (The Ratio Test / Comparison Test/ Root Test/ Cauchy ratio test / Raabe’s Test) to demonstrates that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)p^n$ converges if $|p|<1$?

I tired the ratio test

put $a_{n}=(n+2)p^n$ so that $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{(n+3)p^{n+1}}{(n+2)p^{n}}=\dfrac{(n+3)p}{n+2}$
which gives $$R=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mbox{sup}|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\dfrac{(n+3)p}{n+2}|=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\dfrac{np}{n}|=\lim_{n\to \infty}|p|=|p|$$
@Gary @Kavi Rama Murthy thanks for your comments
please Does anyone know other test to show that the series converges?

Comment: You forgot an absolute value sign. You should conclude that $R=|p|$.

Comment: Taking into account the above comment, continue as $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{(n + 3)\left| p \right|}}{{n + 2}} = \left| p \right| \cdot \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{n + 3}}{{n + 2}} = \ldots
$$

Comment: You can try the root test as well.

Comment: @Gary It doesn't work for me. I tried it

Comment: Why? $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sqrt[n]{{(n + 2)\left| p \right|^n }} = \left| p \right|\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sqrt[n]{{n + 2}} = \left| p \right|.
$$

Comment: Thank you, $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt[n]{{(n + 2)}}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}{{(n + 2)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}}}="(+\infty)^{0}"=1$ true ?

Comment: $$
\lim \sqrt[n]{{n + 2}} = \lim \sqrt[n]{n}\lim \sqrt[n]{{1 + \frac{2}{n}}} = \lim \sqrt[n]{n}
$$ and the last limit is classic, see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1

Comment: So my own way is false. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes because for example $\lim \sqrt[n]{{n!}} =  + \infty$ whereas your way would give $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much