# Compute $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(1+\frac{i}{n})^i)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Here is a question in calculus. Compute the limit of the sequence: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(1+\frac{i}{n})^i)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

There are in general three ways to compute the limit of a sequence of the form in summation:

(1) Compute the sum directly, and then treat it as the limit of a function. However, it seems that it is impossible to work out what $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(1+\frac{i}{n})^i)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is.

(2) Apply squeeze theorem. I think that this is the most possible way to solve this question, but I cannot find a suitable upper bound and a suitable lower bound.

(3) Regard it as a Riemann sum, and then compute the Riemann integral. In this way, we usually need a factor $\frac{1}{n}$ as the length of the intervals in the partition. Hence, it seems that we need to take logarithm and obtain $\frac{1}{n}\ln\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(1+\frac{i}{n})^i$. However, $\ln$ does not commute with $\sum$, so I do not think that this method will work.

Comment: @M.Wind Wolfram Alpha says that this converges to $1$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I think this can be done by Cauchy limit theorem which mean the sum is equal to $ n e$ then $(ne)^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$

Comment: @pie Note that the last term of the sum is $2^n$, whence the limit is at least $2$ (which it actually is).

Comment: @Gary you are right

Comment: What about $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac kn\right)^k\right]^{1/n}-2\right)?$$

Comment: @metamorphy It seems to be $$
 - 2\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2\sqrt {\rm e} }}} \right) = 0.7227012296175 \ldots 
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \text{as @Gary pointed out in the comments $ \ \ \ $} \sum_{i=1} ^n \left( 1+ \frac{i}{n} \right)^i \geq 2^n $$

notice that $2^n$ is the biggest term in the sequence $\left( 1+ \frac{i}{n} \right)^i$ for $i \in \{1,2,3 \dots ,n \}$ then we can do the following
$$ 2^n \leq \sum_{i=1} ^n \left( 1+ \frac{i}{n} \right)^i \leq n2^n$$
$$ 2 \leq \left( \sum_{i=1} ^n \left( 1+ \frac{i}{n} \right)^i \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq 2 \sqrt[n]{n}$$
since [$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{n} =1 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1) then by squeeze theorem
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( \sum_{i=1} ^n \left( 1+ \frac{i}{n} \right)^i \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} =2$$