# Find radius of convergence of the power serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt{n} - 1)^{\sqrt{n}}z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Find radius of convergence of the power serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt{n} - 1)^{\sqrt{n}}z^n$

---

I first tried to use the Root Test.
$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|(\sqrt{n}-1)^{\sqrt{n}}|} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{n}-1)^{\sqrt{n}/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{n}-1)^{1/\sqrt{n}}$

Let $x = \sqrt{n}$ then we have $\lim_{x^2 \to \infty} (x-1)^{1/x} \approx 1$

So the Root Test is inconclusive because we get $1$. Is there another way to find the convergence ? The ratio test doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Hint: $(\sqrt{n} - 1)^{\sqrt{n}}/(\sqrt{n} )^{\sqrt{n}}=(1-\frac 1 {\sqrt n})^{\sqrt n} \to \frac 1 e$. So the radius of convergence is same as that of $\sum \sqrt n ^{\sqrt n} z^{n}$.

Comment: Again, beware confusing the root test with the $L$ as defined in radius of convergence. If the $L$ you defined converges to $1$, then that means that $R = 1/L = 1$ ! The root test would be, given $z$, to check what $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n z|}$ equals. Similarly as you did here, you'd find $|z|$. And hence it converges if $|z| < 1$ and does not converge if $|z| > 1$ so indeed $R = 1$. Do not confuse both methods ;)

Comment: If you compute the ratio and expand it as a Taylor series $$R_n=z \left(1+\frac{\log (n)+2}{4 \sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @NeckverseHerdman Yes in fact this make sense, my brain has some difficulties to understand that but I hope my brain will get it sooner or later. So the radius of convergence is actually really $1$ ? This is so confusing

Comment: @geetha290krm The radius of convergence of $\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}}$ seems to be also $1$, is that correct ? This is so confusing, but I hope my brain will eventually get it soon.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Merci beaucoup ! How did you find this Taylor Series ? I didn't know $\sqrt{n}$ has one ?

Comment: I think my brain is starting to get it, thank you everyone. If someone wants to post an answer, I will accept and upvote it, so the question doesn't appear in the unanswered section anymore. Otherwise I will answer my own question later. Thank you all, this website is so useful for people like me

Comment: @wengen I'll sketch an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are confusing two methods to compute the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt{n} - 1)^{\sqrt{n}} z^n$.

(1) The root test is used to determine when a series (not necessarily a power series, which has a variable) converges. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

In this case, if we choose some $\tilde{z} \in \mathbb{C}$, then the power series converges in $z = \tilde{z}$ is the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (\sqrt{n} - 1)^{\sqrt{n}} \tilde{z}^n$ converges. The series has terms $c_n = (\sqrt{n} - 1)^{\sqrt{n}} \tilde{z}^n$ and *if* the limit $C = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$ exists, then the series converges if $C < 1$ and diverges if $C > 1$. In our case, the limit does exists and similar to how you did, you may rewrite it as $$C = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{n}-1)^{1/\sqrt{n}} |\tilde{z}| = |\tilde{z}| \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{n}-1)^{1/\sqrt{n}} = |\tilde{z}| \cdot 1 = |\tilde{z}|.$$ We see that the power series always converges in $z = \tilde{z}$ with modulus $<1$ and does not converge in $z = \tilde{z}$ with modulus $>1$, so the largest disc in which the power series converges, has radius $1$. Hence, the radius of convergence is 1.

(2) You can also use a criterion to *directly* calculate the radius of convergence, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Finding_the_radius_of_convergence

This method uses the root test and says that, if we write the power series as $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n z^n, \quad a_n = (\sqrt{n} - 1)^{\sqrt{n}},$$ then the radius of convergence is $R = 1/L$, with $$L = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}.$$ If the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ then it is equal to the limsup (this is so in our case) and then $$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}(\sqrt{n} - 1)^{1/\sqrt{n}}.$$ Note that there are no $z$'s or $\tilde{z}$'s in this expression! We have calculated this limit to be $1$ and so $R = 1/1 = 1$ indeed.

---

A quick note about the limit $L = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt{n} - 1)^{1/\sqrt{n}}.$ Because $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is increasing, we can indeed find that this limit equals $L = \lim_{m \to \infty} (m - 1)^{1/m}.$ For large $m$, we have $$(m-1)^{1/m} \approx m^{1/m}$$ so we intuit $L = \lim_{m\to \infty} m^{1/m} = 1$. (See e.g. [How to show that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1))

We prove the limit with the sandwich theorem. Remark that for $m \geq 2$ we have $1 \leq m - 1$ and thus $1 \leq (m-1)^{1/m}$. On the other hand, we also have $(m-1)^{1/m} \leq m^{1/m}$. So, for all $m \geq 2$ we have the following sandwich $$1 \leq (m-1)^{1/m} \leq m^{1/m}$$ and since the outer limits $1$ and $m^{1/m}$ both have limit $1$ as $m \to\infty$, we can happily conclude $L = 1$.