# Evaluating $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac 1n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was trying to rigorously show that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac 1n} = 1$ but so far I have not been very successful. I simply built my argument on what has been already shown, namely that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{p}=1$ for any $p>0$ - the limit then just becomes a special case of this. Do you know of any other way of justifying this?

Comment: Wouldn't that be $0$??? I mean, $\lim \limits_{x\to 0} \sqrt[n]{\frac 1n}$ is "hard", and $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac 1n\right)^n$ is "hard", but this one looks rather straightforward.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76330/prove-sequence-a-n-n1-n-is-convergent/76336#76336) for a more elementary proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$. It's not difficult to apply that proof to this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
n^{-1/n}=e^{-\frac{1}{n}\log n}
$$
and we know $\frac{\log n}{n}$ tends to $0$, so...

Answer (score 0):

Notice, let $\frac 1n=t\implies t\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$,   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac 1n\right)^{\frac 1n}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}t^{t}$$
$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}\ln(t^t)$$
$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}(t\ln t)$$
$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln t}{1/t}$$

Using L'Hospital's rule for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form $$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac 1t}{-1/t^2}$$
$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}(-t)=e^0=\color{red}{1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{1+t_n}.\tag{1}$$ We want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=0$. It is clear that if $n\gt 1$ then $t_n\gt 0$.

From (1) and the binomial theorem we have for $n\gt 1$
$$n=(1+t_n)^n\ge 1+nt_n +\frac{n(n-1)}{2}t_n^2\gt \frac{n(n-1)}{2}t_n^2.$$
Thus 
$$0\lt t_n \lt \sqrt[2]{\frac{2}{n-1}},$$
and the rest follows by squeezing.