# Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}(n+1)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

> Calculate the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(n+1)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

I have tried to use the squeeze theorem and other convergence tests but all failed.

Please, any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$1\le(n+1)^{1/\sqrt n}\le(2n)^{1/\sqrt n}=2^{1/\sqrt n}((\sqrt n)^{1/\sqrt n})^2$$

If we take $2^{1/x}$ and $x^{1/x}\to1$ as $x\to\infty$ for granted, then

$$2^{1/\sqrt n}((\sqrt n)^{1/\sqrt n})^2\to1\cdot1^2=1$$

and the Squeeze Theorem does the rest.

Comment: MSE reference for the fact that $\lim n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76330/prove-sequence-a-n-n1-n-is-convergent

Comment: Absolutely love this answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Use that
$$
\left(n+1\right)^{1/\sqrt{n}}=e^{\left(1/\sqrt{n}\right)\ln\left(1+n\right)}
$$
And
$$
\ln\left(1+n\right)=\ln\left(n\right)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
So it becomes
$$
\left(n+1\right)^{1/\sqrt{n}}=e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$
Using exponential properties
$$
\left(n+1\right)^{1/\sqrt{n}}=e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}}\times e^{\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$
First term tends to $e^{0}=1$ because the power $\sqrt{n}$ is " stronger " than logarithm. And for the second use that
$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{\displaystyle \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)
$$
Hence

> $$
> \left(n+1\right)^{1/\sqrt{n}}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}e^{1/n^{3/2}}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}1
> $$

Comment: the solution is true?

Comment: Why it would not ? Explain me

Comment: Can you explain the last step?

Comment: I've edited it, tell me if it's all clear now. ^^

Comment: The final solutions is right. But it's wrong that you use the symbol ~, which represent asymptotic expansion of some function, or the infinitesimal of the same order. The first term is $e^{2/n^{1/2}}$,  the final result can be written as $(n+1)^{1/\sqrt{n}}$~$e^{2/n^{1/2}}$. I think it is more easier to use the L' hospital rule.

Comment: That's how we write it in France, where l'Hospiral rule is not even taught !

Answer (score 1):

write your Limit in the form $$e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

Comment: What an answer, Brilliant!!!