# The sequences $a_n = \sqrt[n]{4^nn}$ is converge or diverge? Find the limit of each convergent sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

[The sequences $a_n = \sqrt[n]{4^nn}$ is converge or diverge?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYHU5.png)
I don't know how to determine the sequences is converge or diverge and find the limit of each convergent sequence. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76330/prove-sequence-a-n-n1-n-is-convergent). $a_n = 4 \cdot n^{1/n} \to 4 \cdot 1 = 4$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510).