# Limit of the sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n!)^{1/n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, factorial, radicals

Could anyone help me finding the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n!)^{1/n^2}$$

Thank you!

Comment: You will get a better response if you show what effort you have put into trying to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: do you know the limit of $M^\frac {1} {n}$ where $M$ is a finite number and $n^\frac {1} {n}$?

Comment: There are several votes to close this as off-topic. Related discussion on meta: [Why close old questions with accepted answers using the “no context” reason?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/why-close-old-questions-with-accepted-answers-using-the-no-context-reason)

Comment: Another post about the same limit: [Using the squeeze theorem to determine a limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/995508)

Answer (score 13):

use $1<n!<n^n$.and  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

Comment: Thank you. I was looking to use something like this, but was wondering what would be the upper bound for $n!$ that I should use.

Comment: I will add that the limit you mention is subject of several posts on this site. For example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn-1 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1 (and many other posts).

Answer (score 2):

By Stirling formula we have
$$n!\sim_\infty \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$
so 
$$(n!)^{1/n^2}\sim_\infty \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{1/n}(2\pi n)^{1/2n^2}\to_\infty1$$

Answer (score 1):

Try this ($L$ is the original limit) by first logging the function:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n!}{n^2}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \log n}{n^2}=0
$$
Hence the limit of the upper bound is $e^0=1$. Now take the lower bound:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k}{n^2} \geq \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n \log 1}{n^2}=0
$$
Hence the limit of the lower bound is $e^0=1$. By the squeeze lemma $L=1$