# Proof of $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 1$ without using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to prove that

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{x} = 1$,
or
$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\ln(x) = 0$

without using L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Poor L'Hôpital. No one ever wants to use his rule...

Comment: Perhaps you want $x\to0^+$ rather than $x\to0$?

Comment: oh yeah... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer: when $x>0$, $x^x$ is a strictly monotonic function. So it suffices to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1n\right)^{1/n}=1$, or equivalently, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$. You can see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn-1) for various proofs of this. In particular, [Aryabhata's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56358/1551) is easy enough to swallow.

Answer (score 1):

We have to use $x^x=\exp(x\ln x)$ as definition of exponentiation.
Then it suffices to show $\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x= 0$.
Substituing $x=\frac1{e^t}$, this becomes $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{-t}{e^t}=0$, which you may already know. (If not, use $e^t=e^{t/2}e^{t/2}\ge (1+t/2)(1+t/2)=1+t+\frac14t^2$, from the most useful inequality about the exponential: $e^t\ge 1+t$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$).

Comment: could you also solve for me the limit -t/e^t = 0, i don't know how to solve it

Comment: @udiboy I wrote down how to get that: Using $e^t\ge 1+t+\frac14 t^2>\frac14t^2$ for $t>0$, we get $\left|\frac{-t}{e^t}\right|<\frac 4t$ for $t>0$

Comment: I took the liberty to change an $n$ for an $x$.