# Alternating series test question

Tags: calculus

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2/n}}$$

I applied alternating series test. I tried to check if it fulfills the condition that it goes to zero. $\frac{2}{n}$ goes to $0$ . However $n^0$ goes to $1$ despite $n$ being infinity. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You're wrong in the manner of calculus:
$$n^{2/n}=e^{\frac2n\log n}$$
but the series still divergent.

Comment: okay based on the above and apply l'hopital rule i would get 1, which means alternating series test fails right? But if it's 1, the test of divergence also fails so how do i actually proof it?

Comment: Since the sequence
$$\left(\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2/n}}\right)$$ doesn't converge to $0$ then the series is divergent.

Comment: For the limit of the denominator, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn-1/

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{2/n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\ln n^{-2/n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{(-2/n)\ln n} = 1$$
because
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n} = 0.$$
But
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2/n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n e^{(-2/n)\ln n}$$
does not converge to zero. In fact, it does not converge at all. Therefore
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2/n}}$$
diverges.