# The definition of the complex function $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}z^n$ on the open disk, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, mobius-function

I am interested if it is known, that is if was in the literature the following function $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}z^n$$ where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function and $z$ is the complex variable being  $|z|<1$. See below my attempt and my motivation if you want to know why I am interested about it.

> **Question.** For complex numbers $z$, we define the formal series $$ \Omega (z):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}z^n$$ where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function. Does converge this complex function  $\Omega (z)$ for $|z|<1$? How do you prove it? Was in the literature this function? If do you know some remarkable statements from a free-access source, please refer it. **Many thanks.**

*Motivation.* My calculations started from the generating function of Gregory coefficients, see in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients). Then combining it with the Möbius inversion formula for the Taylor series of the logarithm and summation, if there are no mistakes I believe that I can state for $|z|<1$ $$\Omega(z)=z+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n G_n}{k}\Omega \left( z^{n+k} \right), $$ where $G_n$ is the $n$th Gregory coeffient.

**My attempt.** I know the series of the complex logarithm $Log(1-z)$ for $|z|<1$. I want (and I need it as a curiosity from my previous motivation) to justify the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}z^n$$ for $|z|<1$. Then I tried the absolute convergence to state from $$ \left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}z^n \right| \leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \left| z \right|^n }{n}=-\log (1- \left| z \right| )$$ and since the RHS is convergent for our disk I believe that it justify the absolute convergence, this our genuine series is convergent on the open disk.$\square$

Thus I am asking, if my calculation/justification in the section *attempt* was right. Is appreciated as was asked if you tell me if the function $\Omega(z)$ for $|z|<1$ was in the literature, and references. If you know how justify different convergent issues for our function: uniform convergence or analyticity on the open disk, you can provide me the claims/references or hints.

Comment: If some user want (is interested in to know) more details to get the claim of the section *Motivation* I can add in next comment such details. Many  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you proved, the [series is converging absolutely and is thus converging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence), although here is a simpler proof:
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}z^n\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\mu(n)}{n}z^n\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|z^n\right|=\frac{|z|}{1-|z|}$$
This series is also analytic within it's [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence). Using [Cauchy-Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), the radius of convergence [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn-1) $$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\right|}}=\frac{1}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}}=1$$

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer, I need these details. I am waiting if some user know this function $\Omega(z)$ from the literature (because I've curiosity about this function), but your answer is perfect, and solve all my doubts. If in next weeks there are no more answers I will accept your answer. Many thanks for your attention and help.