# Compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}$

If there exists the sequence $x_n = n^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1$ and we have established the fact: $x_{n}^2 \leq \frac{2}{n}$. Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Truly frustrated at this point because I know it is just a small step in my observations that will allow me to draw the final conclusion and not accomplishing it has me very upset. What am I not seeing that would help me along the path ?

Comment: $x_n \to 0$ from its vanishing square and sandwich rule.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn-1?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've already shown that $x_n^2 \leq 2/n$, this implies that $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} \leq x_n \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}$.

Now just apply the squeeze theorem, as both the left and right terms clearly go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: How is that implied?  I agree that $|x_n| \leq \frac{2}{n} \longleftrightarrow - \frac{2}{n} \leq x_n \leq \frac{2}{n}$. But how is this true for $x_n^2$?

Comment: I took the square root. Bear in mind there are two such roots.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
n^{\frac{1}{n}} = \exp\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: WHat does your hint imply? I understand the squeeze theorem form of arriving at the conclusion. But what is your way of doing it?

Comment: Apply the L'Hôpital rule to the argument in order to obtain $0$. Since the exponential function is continuous, the answer is $\exp(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

I propose a folk-solution based on AM-GM inequality. We have
$$
1\leqslant\sqrt[n]{n}=\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{n}\cdot 1\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}\leqslant\frac{2\sqrt{n}+n-2}{n}
$$

The right hand side tends obviously to $1$, so the Squeeze Theorem concludes the proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1.$