# How to prove that the sequence $a_n = (1/n)^{1/n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Using a calculator I can see that the sequence 
$$
a_n =\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$ converges to $1$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

I would like to know the correct way to prove this.

It can also be seen that it approaches $0^0$, is that enough to say that it approaches $1$? As anything to the power $0$ is $1$?

Edit: My logic regarding $0^0$ doesn't work as suggested by @Henning Makholm as the exponential function is not continuous at (0,0)

Comment: You will find much disagreement about whether $0^0$ is even defined. But even if you do define it correctly as $0^0=1$, the exponentiation operation is **not continuous** at $(0,0)$, and thus the fact that $0^0=1$ tells you nothing at all about your limit.

Comment: But is the function continuous for any n>0? If so, the limit should approach 1 right? If not, why not?

Comment: Because $0\not>0$ and **exponentiation is not continuous at (0,0)**.

Comment: I can agree that it is not continuous at 0 and my reasoning that about $0^0$ is incorrect, what I am asking however is: does it even converge? If so, does it converge to 1, regardless of what $0^0$ is?

Comment: You have gotten a good answer to that from Jon already.

Comment: Alright! thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-\frac{\ln n}{n}}=e^0=1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}.
$$
All you need to show is that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1.
$$

Now, take a look at this question and its various answers:

[Proof that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28348/587192)

Answer (score 1):

Also
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{\log n}}
$$
has the form $0^0$, but
$$
\log\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{\log n}}\right)=
\frac{1}{\log n}\log\frac{1}{n}=-1
$$
so the sequence converges to $e^{-1}$

In your case
$$
\log\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{n}}\right)=
-\frac{\log n}{n}
$$
converges to $0$, so your sequence converges to $e^0=1$.