# Convergence of $\sum ( 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} )^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

How can I prove that $\sum ( 1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} )^n$ converges?

I've tried root test, and ratio test, but it was inconclusive.

Wolfram Alpha also says that this sum is convergent by comparison test.

**What series can I use for comparison test**?

Comment: Hint: For $n\geq 5$, $n\log \left( {1 - \frac{2}{{\sqrt n }}} \right) < n\left( { - \frac{2}{{\sqrt n }}} \right) =  - 2\sqrt n$, because $\log(1+x)<x$ for all $x>-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n=\left(\left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}\right)^{-2\sqrt{n}}\sim\frac{1}{e^{2\sqrt{n}}}<\frac{1}{\frac{\left(2\sqrt{n}\right)^4}{4!}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this series converges is by [Schlömilch's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Schl%C3%B6milch%27s_Generalization), a generalization of the Cauchy Condensation Test. Basically, if $u(n)$ is a positive increasing sequence with a uniformly bounded ratio of successive differences, then $\sum_{n} f(n)$ converges iff $\sum_{n} (u(n+1)-u(n)) f(u(n))$ converges. In our case, put $u(n)=n^2$: we have $u(n+1)/u(n)<5$ and the new series is
$$
\sum (2n+1)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^2}
$$Now we can use the Root Test:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sqrt[n]{(2n+1)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^2}}\right|
$$We will split this into two limits.
$$
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sqrt[n]{2n+1}\right|\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n}\right|
$$These limits are both well-known: the [first](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28348) is $1$ and the [second](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358830) is $e^{-2}$. Their product is less than $1$, so we have convergence.