# Prove that : $x_{n}=\sqrt[n]{n^{2}+2}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that : $x_{n}=\sqrt[n]{n^{2}+2}$ is convergent.

---

I intended using inductive method. From inductive step, I supposed $x_{n}<x_{n-1}$, and I need to prove $x_{n+1}<x_{n}$. However, with $x_{n}<x_{n-1}$, I could only show that $x_{n-1} >1$. Please help me, thank you so much!

Comment: Just saying, for a sequence $x_n$ to converge, it is not necessary that $x_{n+1} < x_n$, for eg. $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Maybe this approach works here, i.e. having $x_{n+1} < x_n$ does imply convergence, but the converse is not true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-of-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtnn-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a hint: You can alternatively try using the **Sandwich Theorem**

We have, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n^2<n^2+2\implies n^{\frac{2}{n}}<(n^2+2)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Also, $(n^2+2)<n^3$ $\forall n\geq2\implies (n^2+2)^{\frac{1}{n}}<n^{\frac{3}{n}}$.

So, combining these two, we get,
$$n^{\frac{2}{n}}\leq(n^2+2)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq n^{\frac{3}{n}}$$ $$\forall n\geq2$$

Can you complete this now?