# Need to calculate $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \sqrt[n]{(\ln(n))^{2009}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Calculate:

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \sqrt[n]{(\ln(n))^{2009}-1}$$

I thought about some trick like this one:

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \sqrt[n]{(\ln(n))^{2009}-1} = \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{e^{2009*\ln[\ln(n)]}-1}{2009*\ln[\ln(n)]}\right) * 2009*\ln[\ln(n)]}$$

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

It is important also to add that I can not use L-Hospitals rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\geq 9$, we have $\ln(n)>2$. Also, $\ln(n)<n$. Hence,
$$
1<\left(\ln(n)\right)^{2009}-1<\left(\ln(n)\right)^{2009}<n^{2009}\\
\Rightarrow1<\sqrt[n]{\left(\ln(n)\right)^{2009}-1}<n^{2009/n}=\left(n^{1/n}\right)^{2009}
$$
Using $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$ and the squeeze theorem, it follows that your limit is $1$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-of-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtnn-1), for instance, about proofs of this limit.

Comment: I think that you forgot one $ln$ in the last inequality

Comment: @theboyboy it's not needed because $\left(\ln(n)\right)^{2009}<n^{2009}$

Answer (score 2):

$\ln n=t$

take log on both side
$$\log L=\lim_{t\to \infty}  \frac{{(t)}^{2009}-1}{e^t}$$

By taylor series$$=\lim \frac{1-\frac{1}{t^{2009}}}{\frac{1}{t^{2009}}+\frac{t}{t^{2009}}...+\frac{t^{2010}}{2010!t^{2009}}+....}=0$$

$$L=e^0=1$$

Comment: And without L-Hospitals rule? I can't use L-Hospitals rule, I'm sorry, I will edit my question to include that information. Nevertheless, thank you for your help.